# Generate groovy DSL using swagger

Tags: spring-cloud-contract

The first question I get from most of the developers I get is, Is there any way to auto generate your groovy file by by using swagger or may be plain json file?

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand the question. What do you want to achieve? Do you NOT want to use Groovy file to define a contract? If that's the case then the answer is - you can use the Pact file (a json) to define the contract or you can plugin whatever you want. It's all written in the documentation - http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Dalston.SR4/multi/multi__pluggable_architecture.html.

As for Swagger we don't support it mainly because it's a schema. The reasons behind this decision are in this issue - https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-contract/issues/136

Comment: I am ok with groovy file. But the contract file is very big and if we want to impose regular expressions in the body section, But the links provided by you answers my question.